# Foundation 5 Media Queries Sass Error

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use Foundation 5's new media queries. I created a `foundation_overrides.scss` file and added a link to its css file below the link to my `app.css` file in `index.html` head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/foundation-overrides.css" />
```

...here's `app.scss`:

```
@import "settings";
@import "foundation";
```

...and `foundation-overrides.scss`:

```
@media #{$small-up} { 
  body {background: red;} 
} 
@media #{$medium-up} { 
  body {background: orange;} 
} 
@media #{$large-up} { 
  body {background: yellow;} 
} 
@media #{$xlarge-up} { 
  body {background: green;} 
} 
@media #{$xxlarge-up} { 
  body {background: blue;} 
}
```

Unfortunately this returns the following Sass error:

> Syntax error: Undefined variable: "$small-up"

I've also tried uncommenting the `@import "foundation/functions";` line from `_settings.scss` yet the error persists.

What do I need to change to use these media queries?

Answer (score 1):

The reason its failing is because it can't find `$small-up` variable, or it doesn't exist. Also it will fail if the variable is defined after the media queries.

Try the following:

1. Make sure you are loading `_settings.scss` before your media
   queries.
2. Make sure `_settings.scss` is properly imported: put a `.test {}` class in `_settings.scss` and see if it is in your generated css.
3. In `_settings.scss` make sure the variables are uncommented: for example uncomment this `// $small-up: $screen;`

**Basically your sass should be in this order:**

```
$small-up: $screen !default;
@media #{$small-up} { }
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html

Comment: Hey Kris, thanks for your reply. The `_settings.scss` is being properly imported and loaded before the media queries. When I add your Sass code to my `foundation_overrides.scss`, or `app.scss`, file I get the same syntax error. Anything else I can try?

Comment: I am assuming you now get an error for `undefined variable $screen`. If you had something like this there would be no error `$small-up: test; @media #{$small-up} { .test { color:red;} }`

Comment: Can you post your imports for `app.scss` and `foundation_overrides.scss`? Something is missing or out of order.

Comment: It's the same `$small-up` syntax error. I updated my answer with the contents of `app.scss` and `foundation_overrides.scss`. Thank you.

Comment: Did you uncomment this line in settings.scss? `// $small-up: $screen;` ln: 81 should be `$small-up: $screen;`

Comment: Also try importing foundation before settings: `@import "foundation", "settings";`

Comment: Yes, I uncommented `$screen: "only screen";` & `$small-up: $screen;` from `_settings.scss`. I also imported `foundation` before `settings`. Both changes still result in getting the `Syntax error: Undefined variable: "$small-up"`.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mentioned you to uncomment $screen as well. I am assuming you probably already did that. But I just want to make sure as I am trying to reproduce this on my end.

Comment: Yes, I also uncommented `$screen: "only screen";` from `_settings.scss`. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work then... I have created an isolated demo and it works fine. You can see here. Grab the css from jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4yz6x/, and paste it into http://sassmeister.com/

Comment: Part of the issue has been solved! I removed the `foundation_overrides.css` link from `index.html` and added a `@import "foundation_overrides";` `to app.scss`. Now I'm no longer getting the syntax error. However, the base color of red is appearing at all browser widths (i.e. it's not being overwritten by green or blue). I uncommented all media query ranges. Here's a SassMesiter: http://sassmeister.com/gist/8460505

Answer (score 0):

You've probably solved this by now but no answer as to what was the final cause of the issue was posted. First thing i would check is if you're sass is compiling to the correct css directory in your case 'stylesheets'. Also from your example you're clearly making an error in the name of your file. In your header you have foundation-overrides.css but your sass file is "foundation_overrides.scss". What seems most likely is that you need to change your hyphen to an underscore in your link rel name.

Comment: Yes, I did solve this syntax error (Foundation required specific items to be commented out in 'settings'). The file paths weren't the issue. Good catch on the typo, I just accidentally posted `...and foundation_overrides.scss:` - edited that to `...and foundation-overrides.scss:`